# How to add keyCloak user roles by userName instead of userId

Tags: java, keycloak

Below is the code for adding the role to a keyCloak user.

```java
// Get realm
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realm);
UsersResource usersResource = realmResource.users();

UserResource userResource = usersResource.get("03e7c515d-95e6-4b05-8f24-bd51515536");

RoleRepresentation demoRealmRole = realmResource.roles()
        .get("role1").toRepresentation();

// Assign realm-role role1 to user
userResource.roles().realmLevel().add(Arrays.asList(demoRealmRole));
```

I need to assign role by sending userName instead of userId(line 4). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycloak Admin API does not seem to provide the way to get a user by the user name. So probably this is the only solution:

```java
List<UserRepresentation> usersStartWithUser1 = usersResource.search("user1");
for (UserRepresentation user: usersStartWithUser1) {
    if("user1".equals(user.getUsername())){
        UserResource userResource = usersResource.get(user.getId());
        RoleRepresentation demoRealmRole = realmResource.roles()
                .get("role1").toRepresentation();
        // Assign realm-role role1 to user
        userResource.roles().realmLevel().add(Arrays.asList(demoRealmRole));
   }
}
```